# How to make Resource return json as well

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I have a controller specification generated as below using swagger yaml:

However, earlier it used to return only an image. Now it must send both image as well as JSON based on request field. New field is added as responseType.

How to make sure both are sent as per request either way, please bear in mind not at once?

I'm getting this below error

[incompatible types: `java.lang.Object` cannot be converted to `org.springframework.core.io.Resource`

```
   @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        value = "/api/",
        produces = { "image/png", "application/json", "application/xml" },
        consumes = { "application/json", "application/xml" }
    )
    default ResponseEntity<org.springframework.core.io.Resource> createEmployeeQR(
        @NotNull  @RequestHeader(value = "employeeID", required = true) String employeeID,
         @Valid @RequestBody(required = false) QR QR
    ) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could send the image in the body and the JSON in a response-header but the header must be 8192 bytes max and in charset *ISO-8859-1*.

Comment: @Grim It should be conditionally, Resource when request has image otherwise JSON